# In comparing the exponential and Weibull distributions, why "rate" for exponential and "scale" for Weibull?

Tags: distributions, exponential-distribution, weibull-distribution

When comparing the exponential CDF with the Weibull CDF, we see:

**Exponential**: ${\displaystyle F(x)=1-e^{-\lambda x}}$

**Weibull**: ${\displaystyle F(x)=1-e^{-(x/\lambda)^{k}}}$

I understand how the exponential distribution models time to an event where occurrence intensity is a constant average (the $\lambda$, or *rate* parameter), while the Weibull distribution is similar, except that the probability increases or decreases over time (expressed via the $k$, or *shape* parameter).

In the literature I've read, most of the focus is on how $k$ is the real distinguisher in this regard, and indeed that when $k=1$, the Weibull distribution reduces to the exponential distribution. My question is more about the other parameter: why does exponential have a *rate* $\lambda$, while Weibull has a *scale* $1/\lambda$? What is the difference in meaning in this context between rate and scale? And why is scale expressed as an inverse of the actual parameter? I have even seen in the [exponential distribution Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) that rate is sometimes called "inverse scale," but I am trying to get more of an intuition for the rate of the exponential distribution vs. the scale of the Weibull distribution beyond their being inverses of one another.

Comment: Whether a rate, a scale, or something else is used for this parameter is purely a matter of how any particular writer chooses to express these distributions.

Comment: To expand @whuber's comment slightly, and perhaps too obviously, what is here called scale has the same dimensions and units as the outcome, while rate has the reciprocal of those dimensions and units. If the outcome is some kind of time or distance, rate in particular may seem natural or at least convenient as one parameter. Which is preferred comes down to tribal convention and personal taste.